# Angular - Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{ first_name: null; last_name: null; email: null; img: null; }'

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12 application, I have this component:

```
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

  public loggedIn! : boolean;
  public user = {
    'first_name' : null,
    'last_name' : null,
    'email' : null,
    'img' : null
  };

  constructor(
    private auth : AuthService,
    private router : Router,
    private token : TokenService,
    private users : UserService,
    private api : ApiService
  ) { }

  headers = {     //Token for API Authorization
    'Authorization' : this.token.get(),
    'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = {
      'first_name' : null,
      'last_name' : null,
      'email' : null,
      'img' : null
    };
    this.auth.authStatus.subscribe(
      value => this.loggedIn = value
    );
    console.log(this.loggedIn);
    if(this.loggedIn){
      this.user = this.users.user();
    }
  }
}
```

UserService:

```
export class UserService {

  private header = {
    'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest',
    // tslint:disable-next-line:object-literal-key-quotes
    'Authorization' : localStorage.getItem('token')
  };

  private users = {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:object-literal-key-quotes
    'first_name' : null,
    // tslint:disable-next-line:object-literal-key-quotes
    'last_name' : null,
    // tslint:disable-next-line:object-literal-key-quotes
    'email' : null
  };

  private dataHandler(data: any){
    this.users.first_name = data.first_name;
    this.users.last_name = data.last_name;
    this.users.email = data.email;
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
    if (localStorage.getItem('user') == null || localStorage.getItem('user') === 'undefined'){
    }
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '{}');
  }

  constructor(
    private api: ApiService
  ) { }

      user(){
        const data = localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
        if (data != null && data != undefined) {
          return data;
        }
        this.api.get('auth/user/detail', this.header).subscribe(
          data => { this.dataHandler(data); },
        );
      }
}
```

ApiService

```
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  host = 'http://localhost/myapp';
  baseURL = this.host + '/api/';

  post(url: any, data: any, headers: any){
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseURL}${url}`, data, { headers: new HttpHeaders(headers) } )
  }

  get(url: any, headers: any){
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}${url}`, { headers: new HttpHeaders(headers) } )
  }

  delete(url: any,headers: any){
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseURL}${url}`, { headers: new HttpHeaders(headers) } )
  }

  put(url: any, data: any, headers: any){
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseURL}${url}`, data, { headers: new HttpHeaders(headers) } )
  }
}
```

I got this error:

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{ first_name: null; last_name: null; email: null; img: null; }'

Even when I removed void, the error is still there.

ow do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Comment: What does your UserService look like?

Comment: @perpetual-light - I have updated the code with UserService. Or is there a btter way to handle it?

Comment: Well you won't return anything but void unless your condition is met. I need to see ApiService now to further assess. But you will probably be well served with some async/await sugar. I'll provide an example when I see ApiService for reference.

Comment: also your private member 'users' doesn't match this.user. That could by you will never return anything

Comment: @perpetual-light - I have updated the code

Comment: @user11352561 Can you console.log and check your localStorage?

Comment: Updated Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo here `private users = {` . It should probably be user. Then you will actually have the opportunity for data to be populated. And localStorage.setItem does not return the value that you set. But if even if it did you stringified your object. So you would need to parse it back.

But your UserService could have another problem after that as well. It will probably be best to use async/await.

Like so:

```
export class UserService {

  private header = {
    'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest',
    // tslint:disable-next-line:object-literal-key-quotes
    'Authorization' : localStorage.getItem('token')
  };

  private users = {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:object-literal-key-quotes
    'first_name' : null,
    // tslint:disable-next-line:object-literal-key-quotes
    'last_name' : null,
    // tslint:disable-next-line:object-literal-key-quotes
    'email' : null
  };

  private dataHandler(data: any){
    this.users.first_name = data.first_name;
    this.users.last_name = data.last_name;
    this.users.email = data.email;
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
    if (localStorage.getItem('user') == null || localStorage.getItem('user') === 'undefined'){
    }
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '{}');
  }

  constructor(
    private api: ApiService
  ) { }

  async user(){
        await this.api.get('auth/user/detail', this.header).subscribe(
          data => { this.dataHandler(data); },
        );
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.users));
        return this.users;
   }
}
```

Unless you just want it to be like a cache. Then you should be fine with just fixing the typo. But you will need to return something even if your user member is not populated.

Comment: private users is not a typo. If I change it to user, it complains of duplicate because of async user()

Comment: good point then change this.user to this.users. Or something that makes more sense. answer updated.